# What is the cpu cores caused by GC in Golang 1.4.1

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I have recently come across a situation where one of our Golang app, consuming almost 30GB memory, will periodically eating all 24 cpu cores with nearly almost 100%. This will last maybe for more than 3 seconds. Our Golang version is 1.4.1 on linux 64-bit.

I have googled for some info. Here is my assumption:

- in our app, we use a data type `[]map[string]*list` and the instance of this type will contain more than 250K keys.
- maybe the gc in golang 1.4.1 consuming more cpu time and stop the world. However, i can not find the parameter to configure the parallelism of gc goroutines(threads). And, does it have some relationship with the `GOMAXPROCS` parameter.

Comment: Sounds like this really might be GC.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see where most allocations come from? You could also try to switch to 1.5 which has a better concurrent collector and see if it's any better.

Comment: Better yet, try it with Go 1.6 beta which should be even better with regards to GC pauses. but 3 second pauses on a 30G app seems plausible for go 1.4.

Comment: Ae the others have said, use go1.5 or go1.6. If you suspect the GC, just run with gctrace on to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Can you give some more info, blog preferred, about the gc behavior in golang 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You've really gotta profile to figure a problem like this out.

That said you might be able to reduce the load you put on the garbage collector. Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Linked lists result in a lot of small allocations. Have you considered using a `[]map[string][]whatever_you_are_storing`?
2. Are you adding and removing things from this giant map? Are the things you're adding and removing all basically the same? If so you may be able to use a [`sync.Pool`](https://godoc.org/sync#Pool).
3. Have you tried storing the item directly: `map[string]list` instead of `map[string]*list`. It will change the behavior of your program, but for a small struct it may make sense anyway.

Those are shots in the dark.